# LinqPad6 Can't Load Assembly to Connect to My Project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linqpad

Following the instructions at [LinqPad's](https://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx) site, I tried to create a connection directly to my EntityFrameworkCore project.

As per the instructions, I entered the path to the project's dll in the .\obj directory. I then tried to enter the path either to my DbContext file, or to the cs file. In every case, I get a "Cannot load assembly" error.

Here's a screencap: [image: LINQPad6 Error Message]

The couple of MS packages mentioned in the error message are all installed in the application. I haven't found anything in the LinqPad forums, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

I do know I can use the F4 key to reference the project DLL, but it seems I can't really exercise the service and controller functions in the manner. Besides, I think it would be cool to use LinqPad6 as a debugging platform!

Thanks for any thoughts.

Randy

Comment: Why are you using the obj folder rather than bin?

Comment: Interestingly, an Angular / EntityFrameworkCore MCV project doesn't produce a .\bin, only .\obj

Comment: Which version of Linqpad are you using?